# how can export .CSV file from sqlite data base tables via VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, csv, export

i tried to export data by following cods and it was successful but the first row of data table always miss.for example imagine we have a table like this:

```txt
| id  | name    |
| ----| --------|
| 1   | Jon     |
| 2   | Alex    |
```

and when i ran the following cods it missed the first row and returned content like this:

```txt
| id | name     |
| ---| ---------|
| 2  | Alex     |
```

do you have any idea which what is the problem in my cods?

```vb
Public Function CreateCSV(reader As SQLiteDataReader)
        Dim File As String = Form1.SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim Lines As New List(Of String)
        Dim headerLine As String = ""

        If reader.Read() Then
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim columns(reader.FieldCount) As String
            For i = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1 Step 1
                columns(i) = reader.GetName(i)
            Next i
            headerLine = String.Join(",", columns)
            Lines.Add(headerLine)
        End If
        ''''Data
        While reader.Read()
            Dim values(reader.FieldCount) As Object
            reader.GetValues(values)
            Lines.Add(String.Join(",", values))
        End While
        ''''create file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(File, Lines)
        Return File
End Function
```

Comment: This looks like VB.NET, not VBA ?  I would guess that testing for `If reader.Read() Then` moves the cursor to Row#1, and then when you enter the `While reader.Read()` you're starting with Row#2.   If you want to check for any rows in the resultset then maybe instead use `reader.HasRows`, which will not advance the cursor.  Note if any of your field values contain commas then your file will not be very useful.

Comment: thank you Mr.Williams. i edit the question and also your answer works and problem solved

Comment: You only got the column names in your first Read, which is already in your first row. Then you executed another Read, skipping to the next row